# mongoose link two collection with _id in express and insert id as number or string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

hello I want to create two collections first is room and have some attribute and _id as a primary key or object id I will insert it in post method and the other collection is booking and have some attribute and I want to store id or object id I insert it in the first collection in booking collections to link two collections with each other and can make populate

```
 const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const Schema =mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt=require('bcryptjs');
const  schema  = mongoose.Schema;

 //---------- schema data -------------//
const roomschema=Schema({
     _id:{
      type:String ,
      },
   floor:{
       type:String,
        required:true
    },
    status:{
        type:String,
        enum:['booking','busy','free'],
        default:'free'
    },
    price:{
        type:String,
    },
    bed:{
        type:Number
    },
    offer:{
     type:String,
     enum:['yes','no'],
     default:'no',
    } 
});
const room =mongoose.model('room',roomschema);

const roombooking= Schema({
      _id:
      {
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'room' ,
    },
      bed:{
        type:String,
     },
      price:{
          type:String,
          required:true,
      },
      from:{
      type:Date,
      default:Date.now,
      },
      to:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now,
        },
});

const booking =mongoose.model('booking',roombooking);
module.exports={
    room:room,
    booking:booking
};
```

this is the schema file I make it but I have a errors cast

```
Error: booking validation failed: _id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "12" at path "_id"
    at ValidationError.inspect (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:47:26)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:725:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:293:10)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1949:40)
    at Object.value (internal/console/constructor.js:301:14)
    at Object.log (internal/console/constructor.js:336:61)
    at C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\models\controller.js:103:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  errors: {
    _id: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "12" at path "_id"
        at ObjectId.cast (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:281:11)
        at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1091:12)
        at model.$set (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1269:20)
        at model.$set (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1013:16)
        at model.Document (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:148:12)
        at model.Model (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:105:12)
        at new model (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4700:15)
        at booking (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\models\controller.js:97:16)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at next (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
        at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
        at Function.process_params (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
        at next (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
        at Function.handle (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3) {
      stringValue: '"12"',
      messageFormat: undefined,
      kind: 'ObjectId',
      value: '12',
      path: '_id',
      reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
          at new ObjectID (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
          at castObjectId (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
          at ObjectId.cast (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:279:12)
          at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1091:12)
          at model.$set (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1269:20)
          at model.$set (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1013:16)
          at model.Document (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:148:12)
          at model.Model (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:105:12)
          at new model (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4700:15)
          at booking (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\models\controller.js:97:16)
          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
          at next (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
          at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
          at C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
          at Function.process_params (C:\Users\DC\Desktop\datapage\hotelapptest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    }
  },
  _message: 'booking validation failed'
}
```

and this is insert in room collection method

```
insertroom = function(req,res){
const {_id,floor,status,price,bed}=req.body;

const newroom =new rooms.room({_id,floor,status,price,bed});
newroom.save()
.then(()=>res.redirect('/getroom'))
.catch((err)=>console.log(err));
};
```

and this is insert booking method

```
booking =function(req,res){
    const {_id,price,from,to,bed}=req.body;
    const message={}
    const fee =new rooms.booking({_id,price,from,bed,to});
    fee.save().then(()=>{
        res.redirect('/updateroom',);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
        console.log(err)});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `new` before the Schema like this:

```
const roomschema= new Schema({...})
```

Comment: thanks I try what you say but Still I have the error I edit the post and post more detail like error and methods that can make help thanks.